# сверстать многострочный список с отступами

Tags: html, css

вот html:

```css
.search__name {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0.3em 0;
  background-color: seagreen;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.search__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px #00f solid;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="search__list">
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
</ul>
```

как мне расставить отступы между элементами так, чтобы они были равны отступам рамки? Сейчас отступ у нижней рамки суммируется с отступом элементов. А если я сделаю `margin` справа от элемента, то крайний элемент сдвинется вниз, тк ширина установлена как `1/5` от ширины блока

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```css
.search__name {
  color: #fff;
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  padding: 0.3em 0;
  background-color: seagreen;
  margin: 5px;
}
.search__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px #00f solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="search__list">
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
  <li class="search__name">Not Promised</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: такого рода calc нормально поддерживается браузерами?

Comment: @Nikolay http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: @Nikolay только опера мини не понимает, но можно написать фолбек width: 19%